# Find vector elements that sum up to specific number in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, combinatorics

Let us consider that we have a vector `VEC`.

Is ther a way to find which vector elements can be grouped so as 
they sum up to a given number NUM in MATLAB?

For example if `VEC = [2 5 7 10]` and `NUM = 17`

The requested algorithm should provide the answer that subvectors `[2 5 10]` and `[7 10]` sum up to given `NUM`.

Comment: Are you looking for a solution for small vectors, or does it also need to work for long vectors? (thousands of elements?)

Comment: It would be helpful if the algorithm worked for vectors that contain number of elements from 10 to 50.

Comment: In that case you may want to reconsider your needs. You may have already expected this, but for a vector of length 50 the number of results can exceed 10^14. Perhaps you only need a few results?

Comment: I expexted it really, but I wonder if an algorithm exists that can provide a solution possibly by using heuristic rules, thus avoiding to explore the whole space of possible solutions.

Comment: Assuming `vec = ones(50)` and `num = 25` which solutions would you like to see?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to solve this using [`conbntns`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/map/ref/combntns.html), a function from the Mapping Toolbox that retrieves all possible combinations of set of values (if you don't have this toolbox, you can use [combinator](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/24325-combinator-combinations-and-permutations) from the FEX). So, for vector `A`, for example, we'll find all possible combination of a given length (1 to the length of `A`) then sum them and see which is equal to `NUM=17`:

```
NUM=17;
A=[2 5 7 10];
for ii=1:numel(A)
    B=combntns(A,ii);
    C=sum(B,2);
    D=find(C==NUM);
    if ~isempty(D)
        B(D,:)
    end
end

ans =
     7    10
ans =
     2     5    10
```

Of course you can store `B(D,:)` output into a cell array or whatever for future use...

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to do it without any toolboxes or third party functions. It steps through all possible combinations of values in `VEC` and tests if the sum equals `NUM`.

```
VEC = [2 5 7 10]
NUM = 17;
n = length(VEC);
for i = 1:(2^n - 1)
    ndx = dec2bin(i,n) == '1';
    if sum(VEC(ndx)) == NUM
        VEC(ndx)
    end
end

ans =
     7    10
ans =
     2     5    10
```

This is similar to [natan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14849174/1339280), but without using `conbntns`.

Comment: please [don't use `i` as a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790740/using-i-and-j-as-variables-in-matlab) in matlab

Comment: I do it all the time. I do not use `i` for imaginary numbers. [For speed and improved robustness, you can replace complex i and j by 1i.](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html)

Comment: @Shai I posted my argument as a response to the question you linked.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm not mistaken this problem is NP-hard.
But an interesting approach might be using [`bintprog`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/bintprog.html):

```
n = numel( VEC );
x0 = zeros( 1, n ); % one possible init guess
x = bintprog( zeros( n, 1 ), ...  % objective function meaningless, we look for feasibility
              [], [], ... % no inequality constraints
              VEC(:)', NUM, ... %' we want the sum of selected elements to equal NUM
              x0 ); % changing init x0 might result with different solutions
find( x )
```

the binary vector `x` (the solution of the optimization in `bintprog`) selects the relevant elements that sum to `NUM`

Comment: Very nice approach indeed, but as i understand it, it can not provide all possible solutions (for example in the given example there are two possible solutions, i.e. [7 10] and [2 5 10]). Am i wrong?

Comment: @ApostolosMilioudis - you are correct. `bintprog` searches for a single solution only. However, since the problem is NP complete, this might find a solution faster than O(2^n)...